# AS3: graphics.drawTriangle method strange behaviour

Tags: actionscript-3, graphics, draw, warp

in short, i am using the following circle shaped movieclips as vertices parameter(vector.) of drawTriangles method of graphics class. and using the method on the second picture.

[image: first picture] [image: second picture]

now the thing is first 6 points are working fine but after that all the consecutive points dont make any difference.

[image: with numbering] [image: with grid]

okay here is the code. m skipping circle-shaped-movieclips-drag-and-move-part

```
//cape is instance name of movieclip
//cape width and height
var cWidth:Number = cape.width;
var cHeight:Number = cape.height;

var verteces:Vector.<Number> = new Vector.<Number>();
var indeces:Vector.<int> = new Vector.<int>();
var uvtData:Vector.<Number> = new Vector.<Number>();

//populating parameters of draw triangels
var point:Point = new Point();
for(var i:int = 1; i<=capeSkel.numChildren; i++)
{
    point.x = capeSkel["pt"+i].x;
    point.y = capeSkel["pt"+i].y;
    verteces.push(point.x,point.y);
    uvtData.push(point.x/cWidth,point.y/cHeight,1);
}
indeces.push(0,10,5,  0,1,10,  1,2,10,  2,10,7,  5,6,10,  6,7,10,  2,11,7,  2,3,11,  3,4,11,       
4,11,9,  7,8,11,  8,9,11);

var capeBmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(cWidth, cHeight, true);
capeBmd.draw(cape);
var sprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
addChild(sprite);
sprite.x = 0;
sprite.y = 260;

//this function is called everytime those movieclips are repositioned
function updateVerteces()
{
    var tempVerteces:Vector.<Number> = new Vector.<Number>();
    var point:Point = new Point();
    //capeSkel is the instance name of circle-shaped moveiclip's parent
    for(var i:int = 1; i<=capeSkel.numChildren; i++)
    {
        point.x = capeSkel["pt"+i].x;
        point.y = capeSkel["pt"+i].y;
        tempVerteces.push(point.x,point.y);
    }

    for(var k:int = 0; k<capeSkel.numChildren; k++)
    {
        verteces[k] = tempVerteces[k];
    }
}
function renderView()
{
    sprite.graphics.clear();
    sprite.graphics.beginBitmapFill(capeBmd);
    sprite.graphics.drawTriangles(verteces,indeces,uvtData);
    sprite.graphics.endFill();
}
```

Comment: If the given answer works for you then you must tick it as correct so others know it works. Also not saying "thanks" by vote/tick risks no one working to help you with future questions. He made a good effort for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In updateVertices() you create a temp vector and then fill it with new data just to override the original data during the next step?
Anyway, in first loop you push two values into tempVerteces (Vertices is the proper word) for every "vertex handle" in your container so, length of this vector is `numChildren * 2` but when you copy vertices to original vector from temp vector you still use numChildren.

So, only thing you need to do to solve your problem is change this line:

```
for(var k:int = 0; k<capeSkel.numChildren; k++)
```

to this

```
for(var k:int = 0; k < tempVerteces.length; k++)
```

You doing much more things then you really need to do.
I was so confused about your code that i had to reconstruct this in order to find the problem.
Don't know what you trying to achieve but in this simple case, when you only move one vertex at the time, You don't need to rewrite entire vertices vector - you can just simply replace one item (or more precisely two in this case).

Here is my edit to do the same task along with drag handling:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.Sprite;

var cV:Sprite; //currently draged vertex
var cI:uint; //index of draged vertex
var verteces:Vector.<Number> = new Vector.<Number>();
var indeces:Vector.<int> = new Vector.<int>();
var uvtData:Vector.<Number> = new Vector.<Number>();
var capeBmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(cape.width, cape.height, true);
var sprite:Sprite = new Sprite();

init();
renderView();

function init(){
    capeBmd.draw(cape);
    sprite.x = cape.x;
    sprite.y = cape.y;
    removeChild(cape);
    addChildAt(sprite,0);

    for(var i:int = 0; i<capeSkel.numChildren; i++){
        cV = capeSkel.getChildAt(i) as Sprite;
        cV.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, grabVert);
        verteces.push(cV.x, cV.y);
        uvtData.push(cV.x / cape.width, cV.y / cape.height);
    }
    indeces.push(0,10,5,  0,1,10,  1,2,10,  2,10,7,  5,6,10,  6,7,10,  2,11,7,  2,3,11,  3,4,11,       
    4,11,9,  7,8,11,  8,9,11);

    cV = null;
    cape = null;
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, moveVert);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, clearVert);
}

function grabVert(e:MouseEvent){
    cV = Sprite(e.currentTarget);
    cI = cV.parent.getChildIndex(cV)*2;
}

function moveVert(e:MouseEvent){
    if(!cV) return;
    verteces[cI] = cV.x = cV.parent.mouseX;
    verteces[cI+1] = cV.y = cV.parent.mouseY;
    renderView();
}

function clearVert(e:MouseEvent){
    cV = null;
}

function renderView()
{
    var g:Graphics = sprite.graphics;
    g.clear();
    g.lineStyle(2, 0x00FF00);
    g.beginBitmapFill(capeBmd);
    g.drawTriangles(verteces,indeces,uvtData);
    g.endFill();
}
```

Comment: This answer seems useful so I've upvoted it. I have also edited it since there's no need to tell him he has written bad code... It's why he came to StackOverflow for help.

Comment: Sorry, You are probably right but I meant that except this mistake he made he should revise his entire code. He can change this one line and it will work but it can be definitely more optimized.

Comment: No worries. I skipped his code anyway and then assumed you wrote all that code in your answer just for him (phew). One day he'll be teaching others too :-) ...

Comment: no no.. it is bad code and u are right. bt it is bad code since i am actually NOT manipulating vertices using mouse click. sometimes all the vertices are being repositioned in run time. and yes i try my best to help as many as i can ^^